# Why auto running my python script on startup not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I want to Add a Python script to windows which runs on every start-up so that the python script will run as the windows boots up creating a `hello.txt` file every time. What I'm facing is this issue:

When I run this file manually, it works fine by creating the `hello.txt` file. Then I delete the `hello.txt` file and restart the PC so as to check if it's workin' properly or not. And then it didn't work i.e it didn't created that file now!

Where I am wrong?

**Here's my code:**

```
import winreg as reg 
from winreg import HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
import os              

def AddToRegistry(): 

    def my_funct():
        with open(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\hello.txt", "w+") as test_file:
            test_file.write(r'start here')

    address = my_funct()

    # key we want to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER  
    # key value is Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
    key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    key_value = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

    # open the key to make changes to 
    openfile = reg.OpenKey(key,key_value,0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 

    # modifiy the opened key 
    reg.SetValueEx(openfile,"Testingit",0,reg.REG_SZ,address) 




if __name__=="__main__": 
    AddToRegistry()
```

But when I create the same program with two different files it works:

```
import winreg as reg 
from winreg import HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
import os              

def AddToRegistry(): 

    # name of the python file with extension 
    my_funct = r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python programs\testing.py"
    # joins the file name to end of path address 
    address = my_funct

    # key we want to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER  
    # key value is Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
    key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    key_value = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

    # open the key to make changes to 
    openfile = reg.OpenKey(key,key_value,0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 

    # modifiy the opened key 
    reg.SetValueEx(openfile,"Testing_it",0,reg.REG_SZ,address) 



# Driver Code 
if __name__=="__main__": 
    AddToRegistry()
```

**Testing.py**

```
with open(r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\hello.txt", "w+") as test_file:
    test_file.write(r'start')
```

Comment: What steps did you take in Windows to run the code on startup?

Comment: @kyle-Alm I don't get you... :(

Comment: did you add this python script anywhere in some windows task so that it actually runs on every reboot?

Comment: @Bad_Coder You can see I used this code simply by running it, and when I checked it, it was in the windows registry and that's it... Nothing else. It worked for the first time that is when I run it, and then when I restart the PC it didn't work...

Comment: @Bad_Coder In windows task? You mean the startup folder

Comment: that'll be a good place to start yes.

Comment: @Bad_Coder it's not the case. Because previously I have two files and it was running fine with the same code, but now when I used the single file by adding the code of second file inside it by using a function it is behaving like this.

Comment: Please recheck my question @Bad_Coder

Comment: what value are you expecting the variable `address` to have?

Comment: @Bad_Coder Umm... What value? I just assign it to the function (`my_funct`) / file `testing.py` to get the work done...

Comment: Well thanks @Bad_Coder for helping me :) I solved it by my own... You can check the answer.

Comment: possibly because `address = my_funct()` would assign `None` to `address` as `my_funct` was not returning anything, doing it like `my_funct = r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python programs\background.py"` worked

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by my own & now it's solved! Instead of adding `testing.py` to the `winreg` I add the file itself i.e. `background.py` to the registry and now it's working.

I just simply changed the file name and added a function to it. Here's how:

```
import winreg as reg 
from winreg import HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
import os        

def AddToRegistry(): 

    # name of the python file with extension 
    my_funct = r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python programs\background.py"

    # joins the file name to end of path address 
    address = my_funct

    def the_task():    
        with open(r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\hello.txt", "w+") as test_file:
            test_file.write(r'start')

    the_task() 

    # key we want to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER  
    # key value is Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
    key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    key_value = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

    # open the key to make changes to 
    openfile = reg.OpenKey(key,key_value,0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 

    # modifiy the opened key 
    reg.SetValueEx(openfile,"Testing_it",0,reg.REG_SZ,address) 

    inputs = input(">> ")


# Driver Code 
if __name__=="__main__": 
    AddToRegistry()
```